# Getting blankpage while loading data from servlet into listview in android phonegap

Tags: android, listview, cordova

I want to display json data from servlet in listview of android phonegap. But it is displaying blank page in android emulator. It is not calling servlet also. Here is my code please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>

 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Auth Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
url: 'http://10.0.2.2:7080/example/CaseList',
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data, status){
   $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          $('ul').append('<li><a href="">' + item.case + '</a></li>');
          });

   $('#output').listview("refresh");
 },
error: function(){
   output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
}
  });
</script>
</head>

<body> 
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">    
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false" id="output" data-theme="d">
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% up on ajax calls but I am pretty sure you need to actually call the function after you define it and it doesn't look like you are.

Try putting an onload call in your  tag and then wrapping your ajax in a function.

Body tag:

```
<body onload="getData()">
```

Function:

```
function getData(){
    //place your ajax call in here
}
```